# How to pass function as callback function in node

Tags: node.js, function, callback, common-library

I have created following function in common library created in node to create route.

```
public registerRoute(verb:string,route:string,cb:(req:any,resp:any)=>any):any
    {

        this.app.get(route,cb);
}
```

I am importing this library and calling this function in my another node project like following.

```
logger.registerRoute("GET","/route/testapi",testapi(req,resp))

function testapi(req:any , resp:any):any
{
    resp.send("Function called");
}
```

But I am getting error as cannot find req and resp 
logger.registerRoute("GET","/route/testapi",testapi(**req**,**resp**))

How can I pass this function as callback function to this common library function??

Comment: Try using `logger.registerRoute("GET","/route/testapi",testapi)`

Comment: it worked Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the callback into: `logger.registerRoute("GET","/route/testapi",testapi(req,resp))`

you actually want to just pass the **definition** (method without parenthesis and args):

`logger.registerRoute("GET","/route/testapi",testapi)`

otherwise it will run when you pass it not when it is supposed to as a callback.